# Different menus for mobile and desktop version of site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have one page in desktop version. I need to divide it into two pages for mobile version. I thought about making this pages with the cms (I'm using Wordpress) and add to the links in menu bootstrap classes `hidden`.

Is it possible to make a check box or something else to mark pages which must be hidden in desktop version?

Comment: A checkbox? I won't use a checkbox. Just define in your html/php/css code which page must be visible and which doesn't.

Comment: Not sure what do you want to do with checkboxes here but just using CSS with media screen definitions will work to show different menu layouts in different screen sizes

Comment: I want to manage it in Wordpress, and set the page which should be visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option here is to create two menus, one for the desktop version and one for the mobile version. There are a conditional tag in wordpress called [`wp_is_mobile()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) which you can use to display the menus conditionally. You can try something like

```
if(wp_is_mobile()) {
    //display mobile menu
}else{
   //display desktop menu
}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer because what you are asking to do is not really responsive, it's adaptive and server side is the best approach for this.

Comment: Ok, but how can I chose pages for mobile and desktop menus?

Comment: When you create your menus in the backend, you can decide which pages to add to your menu

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22588613/1908141). It might come in handy